# MySQL SELECT From TABLE WHERE FIELD TITLE Not LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do the following in MySQL

> SELECT * FROM 'table name' WHERE 'field name' NOT LIKE '%string%';

I'm working on a database previously set up by somebody else - there are lots of field headings for shoe size based on location - i.e. quantity_size_125_grantham

I want to run a query that will SELECT all columns and rows from the database where the field heading name is NOT LIKE '%grantham%'. There are multiple columns for quantity_size_*integer*_*location* that I want to rule out.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use back-tick and not single quote on field and table names: `SELECT * FROM \`table name\` WHERE \`field name\` NOT LIKE '%string%';`

Comment: How about adjusting your query to select the fields you actually want to use and not use *

Comment: In addition to Morten's remark, I would also suggest to normalize database, if you got time to do this. As I see it the design of the database is bad and you will for sure lose even more time in the future working with that kind of crap.

Comment: This related question may be of help to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461826/mysql-show-datadictionary-of-tables

Comment: As a last resort you can query the information schema. Look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Comment: @MortenAnderson So that would look like SELECT (column name, ...) FROM table_name; ?

Comment: When you write "field heading name" do you mean "column name"?

Comment: @Aphex22 no parentheses but yes

Comment: @OllieJones - Yes column name

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to dynamically create a SQL statement and execute it within a single statement. It can be done in two steps.

It is possible to retrieve column metadata from the `information_schema` database, from the `columns`, for example:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM information_schema.columns c 
 WHERE c.column_name NOT LIKE '%string%'
   AND c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
   AND c.table_name = 'mytable'
 ORDER BY c.table_name, c.ordinal_position
```

Since a MySQL statement has to define the columns to be returned, it's not possible to dynamically include/exclude columns in a query.

You can use the `information_schema` database to help you create a SQL statement, something like this, as an example:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT '
         ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('t.`',c.column_name,'`') ORDER BY c.ordinal_position)
         ,' FROM `',c.table_name,'` t'
        ) AS stmt
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
   AND c.table_name = 'mytable' 
   AND c.column_name NOT LIKE '%string%'
GROUP BY c.table_name
```

**NOTE:** The length of the string returned by the `GROUP_CONCAT` function is limited by the `group_concat_max_len` and the `max_allowed_packet` variables.

This query only returns a string; it doesn't actually execute the generated statement. That would need to be done as a separate step.

---

<strike>Yes, it's possible. But don't use single quote around identifiers.</strike>

If you need to "quote" identifiers, the MySQL standard is to use backticks around them. (It's also possible to use double quotes if `SQL_MODE` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`)

This:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM `table_name` t
 WHERE t.`field_name` NOT LIKE '%string%'
```

will return all rows from the table where value in the `field_name` column is not set to NULL and the value does not contain the string `string`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not fully following this - I've just used the following and it returns nothing? : $sql= "SELECT t.*
  FROM `product` t
 WHERE t.`field_name` NOT LIKE '%grantham%' AND t.`field_name` NOT LIKE '%middlegate%' AND t.`field_name` NOT LIKE '%chain%'";

Comment: @Aphex22 Please don't use edits to reply to an answer. Either reply in a comment or edit your question if the reply is clarifying or adding relevant info to the question itself.

Comment: I just realized that my comment above can be very confusing out of context. To clarify, he submitted a reply to this answer as a [suggested edit of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4465862) (which was rejected).

Comment: @Adi Inbar: No worries, I understood what you were saying; but appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @Aphex: I wasn't clear what you were asking; I struck out my original answer, and replaced it with an answer to what I think you were actually asking. It's possible to dynamically create a SQL statement, but you can't create it and execute it one step; has to be two separate steps.

Comment: @spencer7593 - Thanks for your help. Am I missing something because this doesn't work. I get a blank screen when running this as part of my PHP report. I'm using $sql="SELECT CONCAT('SELECT '
         ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('t.`',c.column_name,'`') ORDER BY c.ordinal_position)
         ,' FROM `',c.table_name,'` t'
        ) AS stmt
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = '**databasename**'
   AND c.table_name = 'product' 
   AND c.column_name NOT LIKE '%middlegate%' OR NOT LIKE '%grantham%' OR NOT LIKE '%chain%'
GROUP BY c.table_name";

Comment: That query is going to return a column with a label of "stmt". That string will be SQL text which you could prepare and execute to return the resultset you want. It's got to be a second step. (I tried to make that clear in my answer; it requires two steps: one step to build query text, a second step to execute the query text. Also note that the `OR` conditions in your query mean that column names containing `'middlegate'` will actually be included, as long as that column name does not contain 'grantham' and 'chain'.

Comment: If you want to reference a table in the current database, then you can change the literal in the predicate to be a reference to the `DATABASE()` function.  That is, change **this:** "`WHERE c.table_schema = 'literal'`" to **this:** "`WHERE c.table_schema = DATABASE()`".